# Does SetROI work when applying Morphology in OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I'm trying to apply a morphological closing operation *only* to an `nxn` neighborhood of a pixel at (i,j). Easiest way seemed to create a `CvRect` with `cvRect(j-n,i-n,j+n,i+n)`, set the image's ROI to that and then apply morphology.

However, the result is the same as applying Morphology to the whole image, without setting an ROI. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried doing this with the C interface, but here is how I did it using the C++ interface:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat spots = imread("roi.png", 0);

    Rect ulRoi(0, 0, spots.cols >> 1, spots.rows >> 1);
    Mat opening(spots, ulRoi);

    Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(7, 7));
    morphologyEx(opening, opening, MORPH_OPEN, element);

    imshow("opening", opening);
    imshow("spots", spots);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

I have basically just contrived an image, and then only got rid of the "noise" halo in the upper left quadrant. My "noise" spots were only 5x5, so I made the morphological kernel 7x7 to obliterate the noise.

Here is the input image:
[image]

After a morphological opening, I get the following:
[image]

Hopefully that will help you out!